# can I use applymap to change variable names of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If I want to change variable names in a data frame using pandas can I change the names without using pandas.df.rename() function but by using applymap() 
For example

```
Registrar   Enrolment Agency    State   District    Sub District    Pin Code    Gender
Allahabad Bank  Tera Software Ltd   Jharkhand   Ranchi  Namkum  834003  M
Allahabad Bank  Tera Software Ltd   Jharkhand   Ranchi  Ranchi  834004  F
Allahabad Bank  Vakrangee Softwares Limited Gujarat Surat   Nizar   394380  M
```

I need to fill spaces in the variable names in the above data frame  with "_" and all the variable names should be in lower case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) is used for change all values of `DataFrame` element-wise, so for change column names are another methods.

I think you need `list comprehension` with `python str` function `lower` and `replace` (it does not work if `NaN`):

```
df.columns = [col.lower().replace(' ', '_') for col in df.columns]
print (df)
        registrar     enrolment_agency            state district sub_district  \
0  Allahabad Bank    Tera Software Ltd        Jharkhand   Ranchi       Namkum   
1  Allahabad Bank    Tera Software Ltd        Jharkhand   Ranchi       Ranchi   
2  Allahabad Bank  Vakrangee Softwares  Limited Gujarat    Surat        Nizar   

   pin_code gender  
0    834003      M  
1    834004      F  
2    394380      M
```

Or solution with `pandas str` function [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) and [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_').str.lower()
print (df)
        registrar     enrolment_agency            state district sub_district  \
0  Allahabad Bank    Tera Software Ltd        Jharkhand   Ranchi       Namkum   
1  Allahabad Bank    Tera Software Ltd        Jharkhand   Ranchi       Ranchi   
2  Allahabad Bank  Vakrangee Softwares  Limited Gujarat    Surat        Nizar   

   pin_code gender  
0    834003      M  
1    834004      F  
2    394380      M
```

EDIT:

If need change column names by `applymap` it is impossible because this function is not implemented for `Index` (`column names`). But if really want something similar use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda col: col.lower().replace(' ', '_'))
print (df)
        registrar     enrolment_agency            state district sub_district  \
0  Allahabad Bank    Tera Software Ltd        Jharkhand   Ranchi       Namkum   
1  Allahabad Bank    Tera Software Ltd        Jharkhand   Ranchi       Ranchi   
2  Allahabad Bank  Vakrangee Softwares  Limited Gujarat    Surat        Nizar   

   pin_code gender  
0    834003      M  
1    834004      F  
2    394380      M
```

Comment: I don't know that df.columns() give us a list of column names.Thanks for the information, learned a lot!!    I'll use map().

Answer (score 4):

You could do that in 3 ways.

Rewriting the columns

```
df.columns = [x.lower().replace(' ', '_') for x in df.columns]
```

Using string methods

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_')
```

Using `rename`

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.lower().replace(' ', '_'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).lower().replace(' ', '_'))
```

`applymap()` will change the spaces to underscore in the data. If you want to change it in columns, then you can take jezrael's or John's answer.

[image]

Comment: I guess OP wants to rename columns, but i'm not 100% sure. `applymap` looks bit misleading in the OPs question...

Answer (score 1):

Seriously... pick @JohnGalt's answer.  `rename` is the way to go.

But because I like to try to add something other answers haven't covered yet:

Use `split` then `join`

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().str.split().str.join('_')
df
```

[image]

Split and join has an advantage of replacing more than 1 space with underscore `_`